# Angular 11 - subscribe() does not modify the HTML with or without ChangeDetectorRef

Tags: angular

For some reasons, my material progress bar does not hide even if `complete()` is fired and using `ChangeDetectorRef`.

This is the code

```
public pdfDownloadLoading: boolean;
...
constructor(   public clientService: ClientService,
               private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef ) {

        this.pdfDownloadLoading = false;
  }
...
downloadDocs(client: Client) {
    this.pdfDownloadLoading = true;
    this.clientService.downloadDocuments(client.id).subscribe(
      {
        next() {
          this.pdfDownloadLoading = false;
        },
        error(msg) {
          alert( 'Error : ' +  msg );
          this.pdfDownloadLoading = false;
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
        },
        complete() {
          this.pdfDownloadLoading = false;
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

**HTML Component**

```
<mat-progress-bar mode="query" *ngIf="pdfDownloadLoading" style="position: absolute; z-index: 5000;"></mat-progress-bar>
```

Someone has got an idea of what it should be ?

Comment: I assume you effectively call `downloadDocs` somewhere?

Comment: try putting a `console.log()` in your `complete` to  make sure it works. your code looks totally legit